# Variable string in wordpress page permalink

Tags: php, html, wordpress, permalinks

I have a page in wordpress which shows all registered users in a table. When clicked on a user you'll be redirected to their user page. Here is a sample:

```
echo '<tr onclick="location.href=\'/user/'.$slug.'/\'">
            <td>'.$result->firstname.' '.$result->lastname.'</td>
      </tr>';
```

Where $slug is retreived from the database. I have a page with permalink

> my_wordpress_site.com/user

. So if I click on a user I get redirected to a link

> my_wordpress_site.com/user/example_user_slug

Which doesn't show anything because it's obviously a non existent sub page. I've tried something like $_GET in the permalink but wordpress doesn't allow that. How do I fix this?

Comment: you can use get variables in the url!

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't seem to work. Can you post an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<form action="#" method="get">
   User name: <input type="text" name="user"><br>

   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP

```
if($_GET['user'])
echo $_GET['user']
```

if you want to build links you can use add_query_arg() in WP or if you want to deal with the params in a array $query  = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);